# We need to change the meta title tag into the product page programmatically

Tags: magento2, seo

In the di.xml file, we have added the below code.

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View" type="Ghanda\Seo\Helper\Product\View" />
Overridden helper file code.<?php
namespace Ghanda\Seo\Helper\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View as ProductView;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page as ResultPage;

class View extends ProductView
{

    private function preparePageMetadata(ResultPage $resultPage, $product)
    {
        $pageLayout = $resultPage->getLayout();
        $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();

       // $metaTitle = $product->getMetaTitle();
        $metaTitle = $product->getName().' '. $product->getSku().' | '.'Ghanda Clothing';
        $pageConfig->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);
        $pageConfig->getTitle()->set($metaTitle ?: $product->getName());

        $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
        $currentCategory = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
        if ($keyword) {
            $pageConfig->setKeywords($keyword);
        } elseif ($currentCategory) {
            $pageConfig->setKeywords($product->getName());
        }

        $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
        if ($description) {
            $pageConfig->setDescription($description);
        } else {
            $pageConfig->setDescription($this->string->substr(strip_tags($product->getDescription()), 0, 255));
        }

        if ($this->_catalogProduct->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
            $pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, ['_ignore_category' => true]),
                'canonical',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
            );
        }

        $pageMainTitle = $pageLayout->getBlock('page.main.title');
        if ($pageMainTitle) {
            $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($product->getName());
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
?>
```

But, meta title does not change into the product detail page, It is calling from the vendor module.

Answer (score 2):

We can not override private functions.

So, If we need to override `preparePageMetadata` function then we need to override `prepareAndRender` function and create a new duplicate function like `preparePageMetadataCustom` then use that function into the `prepareAndRender` function.

In the preparePageMetadatacustom function, you can add your logic.